# Javascript slider with set background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-sites

I'm trying to create a slider within one of my Google Sites which has a set background, in this case, a circle surrounding the border of the images.

I've managed to get the background to appear behind the slider, but now can't get the two properly aligned.

It seems as though whatever I do, doesn't align them, and I think it's down to both class' being within the same  tag.

However, when I try and have both sets in separate divs I'm then struggling to get the background to appear behind the slider. I've managed to get it above, to the right and below, but not behind.

This is what I've currently got it to look like:[image: Slider as it stands]

Do any of you know how I'd align the images? The code I've used can be found below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  var $slider = $('.slider'); // class or id of carousel slider
  var $background = $('.background');
  var $slide = 'li'; // could also use 'img' if you're not using a ul
  var $transition_time = 1000; // 1 second
  var $time_between_slides = 4000; // 4 seconds


  function slides(){
    return $slider.find($slide);
  }

  slides().fadeOut();

  // set active classes
  slides().first().addClass('active');
  slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);

  // auto scroll 
  $interval = setInterval(
    function(){
      var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

      slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
      slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

      if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start

      slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
      slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
    }
    , $transition_time +  $time_between_slides 
  );
});
</script>

<style>
.slider {

  margin: 0px 0px;
  width: 380px; /* Update to your slider width */
  height: 300px; /* Update to your slider height */
  position: relative;
    text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;

}
.slider li {

  display: none;
  position: absolute; 
    text-align:center;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
}


.centered {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    width: 350px;
}

  .background{
    margin: 0px -150px;
  width: 500px; /* Update to your slider width */
  height: 500px; /* Update to your slider height */
  position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
      z-index: 2;
    }


</style>



</head>





<body>


 <div class="centered">

<ul class="slider">
  <ul class = "background">
    <center><img class = "background" src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B3lcWWaWmAb3YXVIT0ItbjNBVFk"width="500" height="500"> </center>
   </ul>

  <li>
   <center> <img class ="slider" src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B3lcWWaWmAb3T0dzUmdZU3BYdWs" width="380" height="300"> <!-- Logo --></center>
  </li>
  <li>
   <center> <img class ="slider"  src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B3lcWWaWmAb3SEVtekRRWkZIcEE" width="380" height="300"> <!-- Slide 1 --></center>
    </li>
   <li>
    <center><img class ="slider"  src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B3lcWWaWmAb3aHFUQ2U5RHBsbXM" width="380" height="300"> <!-- Slide 2 --></center>
  </li>
  <li>
    <center><img class ="slider"  src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B3lcWWaWmAb3QkN1ZjNtd2VlbEk" width="380" height="300"> <!-- Slide 3 --></center>
  </li>
  <li>
    <center><img class ="slider"  src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B3lcWWaWmAb3cVdUSkprR3BtYzA" width="380" height="300"> <!-- Slide 4 --></center>
  </li>
  <li>
    <center><img class ="slider"  src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B3lcWWaWmAb3UGluMnlrZXJzeXc" width="380" height="300"> <!-- Slide 5 --></center>
  </li>
  <li>
    <center><img class ="slider"  src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B3lcWWaWmAb3UTBMb0I5aTBTcGM" width="380" height="300"> <!-- Slide 6 --></center>
  </li>

</ul>


  </div> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Side note, the `<center>` element was deprecated about 100 years ago (introduced in HTML 3.2, deprecated in HTML 4, and removed in HTML 5). Use CSS instead.

Comment: I spent a fair while working on centering this too! Haven't quite got around to cleaning my code up in that sense yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my first answer on StackOverFlow, so kindly ignore mistakes. Please check update CSS code below (Just replace the CSS):

```
.slider {
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 30px;
    width: 380px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.slider li {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    text-align:center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.centered {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    width: 350px;
}
.background {
    height: 390px;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 10px;
    width: 390px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Here is a live demo with the CSS changes:

http://jsfiddle.net/85k4b5y5/

You didn't managed both circle and slider images with top/bottom/left/right css properties because you have used position to have circle above the images as a mask.

Hope this is what you want!

**Update**: This is the latest working version: http://jsfiddle.net/85k4b5y5/1/

Comment: I just made a fiddle with your CSS changes and it appears to be working. I added the fiddle to your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's made the images align, but for some reason it's now skipping out an <li> so only showing odd number slides (1,3,5,7). Do you think this is related or is it another matter all together? I've got round it by adding extra bullets and halfing the transition time but I'd be interested to know if you know anything.

Comment: @kjexley: I have made changes in HTML to make it clean, css to set all things properly as per design and js a little bit. Please check the update code here.

This is working example: http://jsfiddle.net/85k4b5y5/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your comments on each slider image are wrong, so you are probably not understanding which items you are applying properties to.

eg. look at this comment:

```
<img class ="slider" src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B3lcWWaWmAb3T0dzUmdZU3BYdWs" width="380" height="300">
<!-- Logo --></center>
```

That would make it seem like you are thinking this is the logo, but it is actually slider 1.

If you update this line

```
<center><img class = "background" src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B3lcWWaWmAb3YXVIT0ItbjNBVFk"width="500" height="500"> </center>
```

To be a class of "slider" and a width * height of 380x300, everything aligns correctly.

Comment: I've actually substituted the images and only entered the comments to remind myself which images go where.